# Не получается переопределить метод в LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, коллекции

Создаю LRUcache алгоритм

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class LRUAlgoritm<K, V> implements Cache<K, V>{
    private LRUStorage storage; 

    // Конструтор
    public LRUAlgoritm(int capacity) {
        this.storage = new LRUStorage(capacity);
    }

    @Override
    public V get(K key) {
        return storage.get(key);
    }

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        return storage.put(key,value);
    }

    private class LRUStorage extends LinkedHashMap<K, V>{
        private final int capacity;

        private LRUStorage (int capacity){
            this.capacity = capacity;
        }

        protected boolean removedEldestEntry(Map.Entry<K, V> eldest){
            return size()>capacity ; 
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  "storage= " + storage ;
    }

}
```

интерфейс cache

```
public interface Cache <K,V>{
    V get (K key);
    V put (K key, V value);
}
```

класс раннер

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Runner {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        LRUAlgoritm<String, String> lruAlgoritm = new LRUAlgoritm(1);
        lruAlgoritm.put("1","1");
        lruAlgoritm.put("2","2");
        lruAlgoritm.put("3","3");
        lruAlgoritm.put("4","4");

        /*  for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : lruAlgoritm.) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            String value = entry.getValue()*/

        System.out.println(lruAlgoritm);
    }
}
```

В `Runner` необходимо вывести сколько остается в storage. При выводе остаются все которые записываешь.

Результат вывода

```
storage= {1=1, 2=2, 3=3, 4=4}
```

а должен быть при

```
LRUAlgoritm<String, String> lruAlgoritm = new LRUAlgoritm(1);
storage= {4=4}
```

Отладчиком проверяю, что он делает понять не могу. Но то, что он не проверяет

```
protected boolean removedEldestEntry(Map.Entry<K, V> eldest)
```

Это видно, почему, не могу понять(((

Я пытаюсь создать такого типа логику, но почему в моем варианте должен вызываться метод removedEldestEntry не могу сообразить. Что я упускаю?

```
import java.util.*;

public class LinkedHashMapDemo {
    private static final int MAX_ENTRIES = 2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedHashMap lhm = new LinkedHashMap(MAX_ENTRIES + 1, .75F, false) {
            protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry   eldest) {
                return size() > MAX_ENTRIES;
            }
        };

        lhm.put(0, "H");
        lhm.put(1, "E");
        lhm.put(2, "L");
        lhm.put(3, "L");
        lhm.put(4, "O");
        System.out.println("" + lhm) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: что именно вы не понимает? почитайте [ask]

Comment: @ Mikhail Vaysman,  может так точнее будет, я исправил окончания своего вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы в коде нигде не вызываете метод `removedEldestEntry`.

Ваша основная ошибка в том, что вы не используете аннотацию `@Override`. Если бы вы её использовали, то получили бы ошибку компиляции. Так как метода `removedEldestEntry` нет в предке и переопределить его нельзя.

У вас имя метода написано с ошибкой *remove**d**EldestEntry* вместо *removeEldestEntry*.

Метод который вам нужен - `removeEldestEntry`

```
private class LRUStorage extends LinkedHashMap<K, V> {
    private final int capacity;

    private LRUStorage(int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<K, V> eldest) {
        return size() > capacity;
    }
}
```

Comment: метод removedEldestEntry у меня переопределен и по логике при превышении размера кэша более старый элемент должен удаляться. Зачем и где он должен вызываться. я в своем примере добавил аналогичный рабочий пример, только без создания универсальности через дженерики и в нем все работает. а вот где ошибка в предыдущем не нахожу

Comment: я очень трудно понимаю вот здесь? разве в предке LinkedHashMap нет метода removeEldestEntry? **>Так как метода removedEldestEntry нет в предке и переопределить его нельзя.**

Comment: не заметно как я покраснел чере монитор))) спсибо!!! я бы долго бы еще думал что не так((((

Comment: спасибо теперь обязательно!!! В любом случае из этого вывод, что если  какого-то метода нет.,(а он там должен быть) то самое важное!!!! проделать тщательную работу по грамматике и внимательно посмотреть как правильно пишется метод. учту, спасибо еще раз.

Comment: надеюсь в моих синапсах создалась по этому пункту крепкая ковариантная связь между нейронами))))